# grep multiple column and field

Tags: awk, grep, field

i have this file https://app.box.com/s/qbcvzepzhv1gjbbx9f6fu9by0fsfbr0m

i tried to grep with

```
awk '{print $1 $3 $14}' 1.txt
```

but the output like this

=========================Streams

SrcaddrDelta(ms)

192.168.0.104192.168.0.101

192.168.0.102192.168.0.1010.49

192.168.0.101192.168.0.1040.49

192.168.0.101192.168.0.1023.54

==============================================================

the first value of mean jitter is missing.

and then. i want the output like this:

src ip addr | dest ip addr | mean jitter(ms)

192.168.0.104 | 192.168.0.101 | 3.53

192.168.0.102 | 192.168.0.101 | 0.49

192.168.0.101 | 192.168.0.104 | 0.49

192.168.0.101 | 192.168.0102 | 3.54

pls help me. sry my bad english

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39005782/edit) to include a relevant snippet from your source file, and to format the input and output samples as monospace?  (Put four spaces at the beginning of each line.)  That will make the question much easier to read and understand.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**
The source data doesn't have proper field separator and fields contains spaces. Therefore only using `awk` with `$` position can't produce expected output.

E.g. your field name *"Src IP addr"* will translate to awk as `$1=Src`, `$2=IP` and `$3=addr` etc.

**Solution:**

```
$ sed '1,2 d; $d' 1.txt | awk 'NF = NF - 1 {print $1,"|",$3,"|",$NF}' | awk 'BEGIN{print "src ip addr | dest ip addr | mean jitter(ms)"}1'
src ip addr | dest ip addr | mean jitter(ms)
192.168.0.104 | 192.168.0.101 | 3.53
192.168.0.102 | 192.168.0.101 | 0.49
192.168.0.101 | 192.168.0.104 | 0.49
192.168.0.101 | 192.168.0.102 | 3.54
```

**In details:**

***Command:*** `sed '1,2 d; $d' 1.txt` 
Deletes first (`1d`) and last (`$d`) line as not useful along with original header `Src IP addr  Port    Dest IP addr....` because there are too many whitespaces to deal with.

***Command:*** `awk 'NF = NF - 1 {print $1,"|",$3,"|",$NF}'` 
Here we solve the first problem you mentioned: *"the first value of mean jitter is missing."*
Since your `SSRC` field contains values with spaces that's why you didn't get the 1st value of `mean jitter(ms)`. 
To hack this, `awk` have `NF (last field)` you can manipulate. With your case `NF` would have equal to `Problems` column. So `NF = NF - 1` gives new value by redefining last field sequence number and `Mean Jitter(ms)` column rows become as new `NF`.

***Command:*** `awk 'BEGIN{print "src ip addr | dest ip addr | mean jitter(ms)"}1'` 
Add new header to match expected result.